# How to add a keyboard shortcut to my app Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, xcode7, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to add a keyboard shortcut to my app.
I opened MainMenu.Xib
I added a Menu Item in the File Menu and I named it Snapshot
I Control-Click to First Responder and I connected it to takePicture_click: that is already connected to a pushbutton and the pushbutton works
In the Snapshot MenuItem to the right I added Command-F6
I run the app, it compiles, Snapshot menu item is dimmed, but if I click the pushbutton a snapshot is taken, if I click Command-F6 it beeps and no picture is taken.

I am sure that I am missing something, what is it?

Thanks.

Lennox

Comment: What object implements your action method? Why do you believe it's in the responder chain?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge, it works now, I was connecting to the wrong object.